# Macbook Pro 13" + KVM + 24" LCD limited to 1920x1080 and I need 1920x1200

Tags: macbook, kvm-switch, resolution

My Macbook Pro (unibody, mid 2009, 13") supports the 1920x1200 resolution of my screen, using the VGA display port adapter, but when I connect that through a simple USB + VGA KVM, the resolution becomes limited to 1920x1080, ruining the whole experience.

I'm guessing it happens because the Mac can't figure out what kind of screen is attached to the cable.

Is there a way to work around this?

I've tried SwitchResX but it didn't help. I would add the resolution, but it still wouldn't show up on the list.

Thanks

Comment: Does your KVM support DDC so that it can receive the EDID data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible that the KVM doesn't support resolutions greater than 1920x1080, or that the VGA<->DisplayPort adapter you have has a maximum resolution of 1920x1080. Most DisplayPort adapters supporting resolutions greater than 1920x1080 require some form of external power.

Really though, 1920x1080 is an insanely high resolution for VGA.

EDIT: Does the monitor work with 1920x1200 when connected directly to the display?

Comment: The monitor works with 1920x1200 through the display port and VGA. I'd use DVI, but this KVM is VGA only...

Comment: Oh and the KVM says it supports it on the manual and is powered by USB

Comment: Ah.. don't know then :(